# Отработка httest

Tags: ios, objective-c

Есть задача -в цикле создаем n -ное количество `View`.

- добавляем их как `addSubview` на `self.view`
- сохраняем указатель на каждое  `View` в массив

Вопрос собственно в чем - как перебрать методом `hittest`  все вью этого массива и вернуть ту на которой тач?

Насколько удалось разобраться - метод `hittest` перебирает все `subview` главного вью и не видит вью из массива.

Comment: покажите код, как то очень странно все это звучит.

Comment: добавление view в цикле? - опишите задачу, возможно вы не верно подошли к решению.

Comment: Друзья, спасибо, вопрос решен. Разобрался -все оказалось проще - hittest  возвращает верхний элемент именно UIView. А я добавлял UIImageView и перебирал их